# Firefox 71.0 goes looping and eating all memory on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, firefox

From time to time Firefox takes all resources (memory and cpu) such that it freezes, and I can no longer Alt-F3 to switch to tty3 nor move the mouse.

This happens quite frequently in the last months, also quite frequently single tabs are shown as crashed.

What are the best ways to solve this, apart from powering off my laptop?

(Everything is up to date as of today)

The following is just as demanded by @heynnema

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        3,5G        1,4G        657M        2,8G        3,2G
Swap:          975M          0B        975M
```

and some days later, when I just encountered that problem again (but only for some moments):

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        4,1G        1,8G        577M        1,7G        2,7G
Swap:          975M        1,5M        974M
```

so swap was used a tiny bit.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`.

Comment: You can try to start a new profile in Firefox and see if the problem persists. To achieve that you need to start firefox via terminal with the `-P` flag --> `firefox -P`.